# How to filter map values based on key value pair

Tags: list, dictionary

I have map values in an object Array:

```json
[
  { name: "xxx", class: "10", gender: "M" },
  { name: "yyy", class: "9", gender: "M" },
  { name: "zzz", class: "10", gender: "F" },
  { name: "aaa", class: "8", gender: "M" },
  { name: "bbb", class: "7", gender: "F" },
  { name: "ccc", class: "6", gender: "M" },
]
```

I need to fetch only gender with value with either "M" or "F".

Comment: `let result = array.filter(item => item.gender === "M");` is that what you want?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).